# Testing for Constant Hazard Function

Tags: survival, hazard, weibull-distribution, exponential-distribution

My colleagues and I have some unemployment data, and we'd like to test the hypothesis that it's drawn from a memoryless distribution (= constant hazard function). Is there a standard test for this?

(I'm aware of the ["one sample" log-rank test](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/One-Sample_Logrank_Tests.pdf). But the only way I can see to apply it in our situation feels questionable. That is, we could fit a memoryless model to our data, then use its predictions as the "expected number of events" [$E$ in the linked description]. But I'm worried this would be methodologically sketchy—though I can't articulate why exactly.)

Comment: One idea is to fit the data to a Weibull distribution, and check that the power term (depends on the parameterization) is close to zero. This is the same as checking for a constant vs monomial, time dependent hazard.

Comment: Thanks, yea, we can check this way informally. But we're wondering if there's a (standard) test-statistic that will give us a $p$-value we can use for formal reporting purposes.

Comment: You can still get a p-value out of this calculation. It's not a "standard" test like a t-test, but I personally wouldn't see it as worth less than any other test.

Comment: Thanks again. I was hoping there'd be some lit on this statistic (e.g. its sufficiency and other properties). But I guess not judging by the lack of responses.